# Check content type of a comma separated values

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

txt with strings like this every line:

```
85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42,1813724,client@gmail.com
13vg4f20-fc24-604f-2ccc-1af23taf4421,4255729,developer@gmail.com
```

I need to check if the "first" value before the comma is a type like that, "second" the other id which is only numbers, and the last is email field, before the line break.

I've tried some codes but no one work and I'm very lost at this because I don't know how can achieve this feature.

Comment: what codes have you tried. Please provide them along with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string with `,` and apply the regex to all elements separately. There will be email, alphanumeric-strings, and numbers with specific lengths.

```js
function test(str){

  let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; // email regex

  str = str.split(","); 

  // string should be of length 3 with str[1] number of length 7
  if(str && str.length === 3 && Number(str[1]) && str[1].length === 7 ){

    let temp = str[0].split("-");

    // check for 85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42 separately.
    if(temp && temp.length === 5 &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{8}/.test(temp[0]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[1]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[2]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[3]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{12}/.test(temp[4])){

      // email regex
      if(regex.test(str[2])){
        return true;

      } 
      else{
        return false;
      }

    }
    else{

      return false
    }
  }
  else{

    return false;
  }
}


console.log(test('85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42,1813724,client@gmail.com')); //true
console.log(test('13vg4f20-fc24-604f-2ccc-1af23taf4421,4255729,developer@gmail.com')); //true
console.log(test('13vg4f20-fc24-604-2ccc-1af23taf4421,4255729,developer@gmail.com')); //false
console.log(test('13vg4f20-fc24-604-2ccc-1af23taf4421,4255729,developer@gmailcom')); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Split this string by comma separator.

```
var str = '85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c5ad62ee93f42,1813724,client@gmail.com';
```

You will get array of String Once you split it.

```
var strArr = str.split(',');
```

And after that You have to match your `Email` string with `RegEX`

```
 var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
 reg.test(strArr[2])
```

likewise you can do this for first two string also

Comment: For that you have to apply other RegEX

Comment: For that it will require additional logic if string has a variable number of commas.

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer that you can do for other part of string also. I just provided for email part.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12},[0-9]+,[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

> ^ represents the start of the line
>
> $ represents the end of the line
>
> [a-zA-Z0-9]{8} represents a-z, A-Z, 0-9 total of 8 charectors

You can test regex at this link

https://regex101.com/r/VABJ7q/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regex? For my way try something like this:

```
let string = '85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42,1813724,smileydesign9@gmail.com';

string = string.split(',');
const code = string[0].match(/(-?[a-z0-9]+)+/g).length === 1;
const number = string[1].match(/[0-9]+/g) .length === 1;
const email = string[2].match(/[a-z0-9]+\@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{0,3}/g) .length === 1; 

console.log(code, number, email) ;
```